# Dataquest exercise, my answer was close but won't work. How come?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm really just here to try and answer why my method didn't work to answer the exercise question.

We were provided a csv file, went through some exercises to extract from it sums of births from each year, day of the week, month, etc. Here is a short head - year, month, day of the month, day of the week, number of births.

```
[[1994, 1, 1, 6, 8096],
 [1994, 1, 2, 7, 7772],
 [1994, 1, 3, 1, 10142],
 [1994, 1, 4, 2, 11248],
 [1994, 1, 5, 3, 11053]]
```

This last exercise was to generalize our previous exercises so that COLUMN selects a day and FILE could be any CSV file. I know there are many ways to simply import CSVs, but I think they want us to go through the trouble as newbies. lol Anyway, it returns the entire list no matter my input for column. Confusing.

```
def calc_counts(file, column):
births_sum = {}
new = open(file, 'r').read()
string_list = new.split('\n')[1:]
final_list = []
#loop to INT() 
for row in string_list:
    int_fields = []
    string_fields = row.split(',')
    for value in string_fields:
        int_fields.append(int(value))
    final_list.append(int_fields)
return final_list     
for row in final_list:
    births = row[4]
    column_value = final_list[column]
    if column_value in births_sum:
        births_sum[column_value] += births
    else:
        births_sum[column_value] = births
return births_sum
```

Edit: After some suggestions about removing the first return, this is what I'm receiving -

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: It should actually say "`IndentationError`"...

Comment: Also: you have a leftover `return final_list` between your two for loops. Essentially a typo.

Comment: Wasn't a typo, I mean it worked somewhere else and kept it haha so I guess I don't ultimately understand the purpose of return...so that sucks.

Comment: Do you understand it now? And exactly how are you callig your function?

Comment: Nevermind: the error is straightforward. You're constructing a list of lists in `final_list`, so `column_value = final_list[column]` gives you a list for `column_value`, which is indeed not hashable, so you can't use it as a key in the dict called `births_sum`. You probably don't want that to be a list: what should the code be doing? If `final_list` is not supposed to be a list of lists, you might have meant `final_list.extend(int_fields)` instead of `.append()`.

Answer (score 0):

---

##

```
 def calc_counts(fileName,col):
    '''opening the file and counting the births of specified column'''
    file = open(fileName,'r')
    file_reader = file.read()
    data = file_reader.split('\n')[1:]
    #to store the converted int (list of lists)
    final_list = [] 
    #to store the birth count in dictionary
    birth_count_dict = {} 
    for row in data:
        #to store the int values
        int_list = [] 
        string_field = row.split(',')
        for value in string_field:
            int_list.append(int(value))
        final_list.append(int_list)
    '''loop to count the birhts and to append to the dictionary '''
    for line in final_list:
        births = line[4]
        column = line[col]
        if column in birth_count_dict:
            birth_count_dict[column] += line[4]
        else:
            birth_count_dict[column] = 0
    return birth_count_dict

calc_counts("US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv",1)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to describe how the user's example failed and how your solution addresses the failures.

Answer (score -1):

When you `return final_list`, your function ends there, so it doesn't get the chance to continue.

Just remove that line, or split it into two functions where the first feeds into the second.

Comment: If this is the case, I can't for the life of me understand why the births_sum dictionary is populating.

Comment: @seapea - In any case, you need to indent your code so we know exactly how the code is running because it shouldn't as is.